# AWS Codepipelines with using S3 as a trigger. Is zip only supported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

So, I have a codepipeline that is triggered based on an update to one single file, a json file.

I noticed that it does trigger when the file gets updated,but I get the error

zip: not a valid zip file for secondary source

If I change it to a zip file, it seems to work.  So, S3 as trigger points for codepipeline only support zip?

Answer (score 0):

AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-S3.html) says that you may specify single file as source in pipeline. Make sure your pipeline still works without zip file.

Comment: Ya i did that, but I get the error above that says zip: not a valid zip file for secondary source

Comment: what did you specify as a "S3 object key" under pipeline is it a zip file or a json file ? If you specify a zip file as a object key then pipeline expects a zip file and when found a josn , you see the exception

Comment: when i specify   blah.json, it works. I think it has to do with the output from the source. It has to be a zip file. Not sure why. I tried a .json as and output but it gives me that error